# How do i define routing to navigate to details page when link clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing

I need some help to implement list and details page.

I have `motorList.html` page where i am listing all motors as `hyperlink` retrieved from server (database).

**motorList.html**

```
<div>
    <ul class="phones">
        <li ng-repeat="motor in motors" >
            <a href="#/motors/{{motor.Id}}">{{motor.Name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want when user clicks on any motor link, system should navigate to `motorDetails.html` page and show the details for clicked/selected motor.

For this i defined my routes as following in app.js

**app.js**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/motors', {
            templateUrl: 'View/motorlist.html',
            controller: 'motorController'
        }).
        when('/motors/:motorId', {
            templateUrl: 'View/motordetail.html',
            controller: 'motorDetailsController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/motors'
        });
  }]);
```

**motorDetails.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul class="phones">
            <li ng-repeat="motor in motors" class="thumbnail">
                <p>{{motor.Name}} {{motor.Make}} {{motor.Model}} {{motor.Year}} {{motor.Kilometers}} {{motor.Price}} {{motor.Color}} {{motor.SellerType}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**motorDetailsController.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);
app.controller('motorDetailsController', function ($scope, $routeParams, motorService) {

    $scope.motors = null;

    $scope.getMotorDetails = function (Id) {
        motorService.getByMake(Id)
             .success(function (motors) {
                 $scope.motors = motors;
             })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load motor data: ' + error.message;
        });
    }
});
```

**Problem:**
When i click on any motor hyperlink, it does not navigate to `motorDetails.html` page but url changes e.g. `http://localhost:12270/View/motorList.html#/motors/161`.

I am new to AngularJs routing and for sure i am missing something here but not sure what is wrong.

Could anyone guide me please.
Thanks

Comment: Where do you have the `ng-view`?

Comment: I dont have and not sure where i should define it and what it does. Can you guide me?

Comment: See answer from Pankaj. You place it where you want your template to load.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `ng-view` directive on your page, which will show the `template` loaded from the `$routeProvider` by watching the `URL`. You need to add `ng-view` directive somewhere in your body.

Additionally you should incorporate the changes suggested by `@Dvir`.

**Markup**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul class="phones">
            <li ng-repeat="motor in motors" class="thumbnail">
                <p>{{motor.Name}} {{motor.Make}} {{motor.Model}} {{motor.Year}} {{motor.Kilometers}} {{motor.Price}} {{motor.Color}} {{motor.SellerType}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

**Update**

Ideally you should have `ng-view` directive there in `motorList.html`, which gets loaded(But I'm treating it as the index.html page where all the css & js references are there)

Also you don't need to include the `html`, `head` & `body` tag in `partial` as its going to treated as partial, So remove `body`,`head` & `html` tag and make it simple by placing required template only.

**motorDetails.html**

```
<div>
    <ul class="phones">
        <li ng-repeat="motor in motors" class="thumbnail">
            <p>{{motor.Name}} {{motor.Make}} {{motor.Model}} {{motor.Year}} {{motor.Kilometers}} {{motor.Price}} {{motor.Color}} {{motor.SellerType}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just checked and validating your answer. please give me few seconds.

Comment: this     <div ng-view></div> has to be added in motorList.html or motorDetails.html?

Comment: @simbada no..It should be added in the body.. Look at the snippet which I have added in my answer.. If you add that in `partial` then it never get work..

Comment: Unless / until i am doing some disaster mistake, your advised solution did not workout for me. i added ng-view tag in motorList.html file but still when I click on link, the url changes but does not navigate to motorDetails.html page. What should i do now? I don't understand what html pages you're calling partial view. See, I have two html views i.e. motorList.html and motorDetails.html. In motorList.html  i have links, when i click on it than motorDetails.html should load with details. When you say ".It should be added in the body." body of which HTML file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97076/discussion-between-simbada-and-pankaj-parkar).

Comment: No luck so for.. Not sure what i am missing here. Anybody have idea please?

Comment: @simbada Please create a fiddle or plunkr with replication of problem in it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `href` is a regular attribute and it's not evaluated by angularJs.
To make this expression to be your desired link you have to use `ng-href` so angularJs will evaulate the expression and assign it to an `href` html attirbute.

You have to change

```
href="#/motors/{{motor.Id}}"
```

to

```
ng-href="#/motors/{{motor.Id}}"
```

In addition to get its id. you have to use `$routeParams` in the controller.
For instance:

```
var id = $routeParams.motorId
```

**UPDATE**
I missed that but @Pankaj Parkar right. You have to use `ng-view` to make the `routeProvider` to assign the relevant view to the right placeholder.

How to use `ng-view` ?
You have to make an element where do you want to make the view appear.
It can be part of the page or all the page.
Put the element wherever you want and you'll understand.

For instance:

```
<body>
   <div id="nav">
   </div>
   <ng-view>
     <!-- this is the place your html template will apear -->
   </ng-view>
</body>
```

Comment: Unless i missed something but your solution did not work for me.

Comment: Can you please have a look to my last comment posted to Pankaj comments?